# I am trying to write jQuery / JavaScript code which fades in a list of words into a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, fadein

I am trying to write some JavaScript / jQuery code which will enable a `<h1>` element in webpage to cycle though a list of words.  The words will fade in and out.  I can't get it to work.  I think the while statement is running too quickly and not stopping.  Could somebody please assist; I have spent hour trying to fix it.

```js
var x = 5;
var calls = 10;
var words = ["cat", "dog", "fish"];

while (calls > 0) {
  setInterval(myfunc, 2000);
  calls = calls - 1;
}

function myfunc() {
  if (x > 2) {
    x = 0;
  }
  $("h1").fadeToggle(5000).html(words[x]);

  x = x + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="myText"></h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in another way, for instance using a `for` loop and `await`ing the animations :

```js
const words = ["cat", "dog", "fish"],
   $text = $("h1.myText");

const run = async () => {
 for( let word of words ){
  console.log("word = " + word)
  $text.hide().text(word);
  await $text.fadeIn(2000).promise()
  await $text.fadeOut(2000).promise()
 }
}

run()
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size : 3rem;
  color : green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="myText"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post it really helped.  i added a while loop for it runs continuously.  Now I need to learn what promise and awaits are.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` keeps running every x seconds until it is cleared. One way to achieve your goal is to use `setTimeout()` instead, which only runs once after x seconds, or remove the `while` block and stop the interval with `clearInterval` after a number of calls from within your function like so:

```js
var x = 5;
var calls = 10;
var words = ["cat", "dog", "fish"];

var interval = setInterval(myfunc, 2000);

function myfunc() {
  if (x > 2) {
    x = 0;
  }
  $("h1").hide();
  $("h1").html(words[x]).fadeToggle(2000);
  x = x + 1;
  calls = calls - 1;
  if (calls < 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you.  You have made me realise I have just wasted 3 hrs of my life by using setInterval instead of setTiimeout.